# How can we allocate a direct CharBuffer if we don't have any respective (allocateDirect) methods in `CharBuffer` or `Buffer`?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, charbuffer

Why do we have  `isDirect()` method in CharBuffer?

How can we allocate a direct CharBuffer if we don't have any respective (allocateDirect) methods in `CharBuffer` or `Buffer` ?

I may guess it is:

```
ByteBuffer.alocateDirect(100).asCharBuffer()
```

Is this so and is it the only (and recommended) way to do it?

Comment: A char is not a byte in Java

Comment: I added an explanation for the U/S/R suffixes.

Comment: Do you need other clarifications?

Answer (score 1):

`CharBuffer` inherits that method from the `Buffer` interface, with many others.
`CharBuffer` has multiple sub-classes

[image]

For example the `DirectCharBuffer`(s) return `true`.
This

```
ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(20).asCharBuffer();
```

will return a `DirectCharBuffer`, which is a `CharBuffer`.

`*U` suffix for big-endian systems.
`*S` suffix for other kinds (little-endian).
`*R` suffix for read-only buffers.

---

```
final CharBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(20).asCharBuffer();
final boolean direct = cb.isDirect();  // true
```

---

> Is this so and is it the only (<s>and recommended</s>) way to do it?

Yes.

---

For reference, what is a direct buffer? See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), section *Direct vs. non-direct buffers*.